# jQuery .animate() not working, but .css() does

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a mouseover animation using this code:

```
var menu = {
    colors: [ '#B8410D', '#1C70A8', '#27A328', '#B59215' ],

    alignMenuLeft: function() {
        var slider_div = jQuery('#slider-1');
        var menu_div = jQuery('#dupl-menu');
        var offset = slider_div.offset();

        menu_div.css({
            'top': offset.top,
            'left': offset.left + slider_div.width() - menu_div.width()
        });
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slider-1').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade',
        animSpeed: 500,
        pauseTime: 4000,
        controlNav: false,
        captionOpacity: 0,
        directionNav: false,

        afterLoad: menu.alignMenuLeft
    });

    $('#dupl-menu .menu-item').mouseover(function() {
        console.log('mouseover');
        $(this)
            .stop()
            .animate({
                    borderRightColor: menu.colors[$(this).index()],
                    borderRightWidth: '6px',
                    borderRightStyle: 'solid'
                },
                { queue: false, duration: 600 });
    });

});

jQuery(window).resize(menu.alignMenuLeft);
```

**([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xDkF/))**

However, it doesn't work. If I add a function as the 3rd parameter of `.animate` to log the completion, it never gets called. But if I use `.css` in place of `.animate`, it does work, so the selector is correct. What could cause this problem?

Edit:

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="dupl-menu">
    <div class="menu-main-container">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-50"><a href="#item1">item1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href="#item2">item2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-52"><a href="#item3">item3</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53"><a href="#item4">item4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: can u post the html also

Comment: are you sure this `menu.colors[$(this).index()]` is valid? log it to the console.

Comment: Works for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/)

Comment: it worked for me in the fiddle too, but not when I pasted the whole JS. I have updated the post and added a fiddle with the complete source as well.

Comment: if you hit F12 and open up the console, you'll see that the script halts because nivoSlider is missing. And without the nivoSlider functions it works, again, just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xDkF/1/)

Comment: dang it, that's right. If I remove the nivo part, it works in the fiddle. How can I analyze what's different between the fiddle and the real site?

Comment: Firstly, use Chrome or Firefox and open the console (F12) and see if there are any obvious errors popping up in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was two-fold: one problem was, as many people mentioned, that I need jquery-ui for the animations to work on these properties. The second issue was that the li elements originally did not have a border property. I added

```
#dupl-menu .menu-item {
  border-right: 0 solid white;
}
```

To the CSS and now it works as it should (and this is what was different in the fiddle).

Answer (score 3):

You may need **jQuery UI** to adjust certain properties.

Check out my example based on your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4xf9/

I improved your code a little in places, hopefully it's more clearer now. I prefer to use the new `"on"` event handler with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

I accentuated the border size and colour to make the change more obvious.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** I wasn't sure what `menu.colors[$(this).index()` was, so I left it out and replaced it with a simple string colour keyword...but you can swap this out easy enough.

Comment: I have included jquery UI like this: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=3‌​.4.2'></script>`. It still doesn't work, but I can animate the width property regardless, so I guess this will be the root cause. How can I make sure it's loaded? jQuery.ui is defined, but it still won't work.

Comment: If you use Document ready in jQuery, then that should work. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29 . Also, the order of script files should be: 1. jQuery core 2. jQuery UI 3. Your jQuery code.

Comment: I had the same problem and I needed JQuery UI

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to do color animation you need to include jQuery UI.

Refer [jQuery UI color Animation](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Comment: Which jquery-ui version do I need for jQuery 1.7.2?

Comment: Any latest version and the dependent latest jQuery.js version. As of now jQuery UI is 1.9.2 and jQuery is 1.8.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery UI if you want to animate colour styles. The vanilla animate() is used for more basic things; basically anything that's controlled via CSS through integer values (position, opacity, height, width etc. - but not colour. You need a separate plugin for that, or jQuery UI).

Comment: I have included jquery UI like this: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=3.4.2'></script>`. It still doesn't work, but I can animate the width property regardless, so I guess this will be the root cause. How can I make sure it's loaded? `jQuery.ui` is defined, but it still won't work.

Comment: Try running a local copy of jQuery UI rather than a linked library to see if that solves the issue. Pages *should* download all the libraries before running any functions, though, so I doubt that's the cause...

Answer (score 1):

It works once you resolve this TypeError on Fiddle:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'
```

After deleted few jQuery lines works for me:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6xDkF/5/